# Can a Microsoft Find Time poll be embedded into a web page?

Tags: outlook, calendar, microsoft-teams

Is it technically possible to use the plugin Microsoft Find Time for an iframe embed to schedule a Microsoft Teams meeting together in a Microsoft Outlook calendar with other accounts using external e-mail addresses?

What other free or commercial tools come to your mind for such a use case, preferrably with location in EU and fully compliant to EU-GDPR with a template of what to add in the data privacy statement.

One tool I already know, but which can't be customized enough for the given use case is Appointlet.

Also, a Microsoft Bookings licence is currently no option.

Are there equal or better alternatives?

Kind regards and thanks,

Comment: Are you developing any teams app? or looking for tool?

Comment: Looking for a tool @Sayali-MSFT